# Coordinate of each part of body in .mhx

Tags: animation, blender-internal-render-engine, coordinates, makehuman

I am imported a *.mhx file in blender to do a walk animation. I remark that each control FK/IK has a seperate coordinate system. However, I need to get the coordinate of each part of model (feet,..) in the world coordinate system (master).
For example here , the z coordinate of  the foot is negative but in the master coordinate system it will be positive. I need that to get the long of the stride for example and to check the position of feet on the ground.

[image]

Comment: As this is a custom shape, the real bone can be somewhere else than the shape you see.

Comment: @Bithur I did not understand what do you mean?

Comment: a custom shape is a representation of the bone, not the bone itself. The shape's position is not the real bone's position, it's placed here for conveniance. go in armature settings and uncheck the "shapes" display to see the real bone.